# Can an existing GKE cluster be made private?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I've got an existing GKE cluster and I'd like to configure it with private nodes as per [the GKE hardening guide](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/hardening-your-cluster#restrict_network_access_to_the_control_plane_and_nodes).

It seems like the possibility for selecting a private cluster is disabled in the cluster configuration UI, and setting it in Terraform with a `private_cluster_config` block forces destruction of the cluster.

Is there no way to configure private nodes for an existing cluster?

Comment: I don't find how to do the "enable-ip-alias" on an existing cluster. i fear that you have to redeploy your cluster.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately at this point it is not possible:

[You cannot convert an existing, non-private cluster to a private cluster.](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/private-clusters#req_res_lim)